# Activating a Void On Button Press

Tags: c#, button, onclick, void

Pretty straight forward question, I've just forgotten the correct coding to do it. I have a void set up and I want it to run when I click a button.

Void I want executed:

```
    public void giveWeapon(int clientIndex, string weaponName)
    {

        uint guns = getWeaponId(weaponName);

        XDRPCExecutionOptions options = new XDRPCExecutionOptions(XDRPCMode.Title, 0x822728F8);  //Updated
        XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint> info = new XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint>(getPlayerState(clientIndex));
        XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint> info2 = new XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint>((uint)guns);
        XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint> info3 = new XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint>((uint)0);
        uint errorCode = xbCon.ExecuteRPC<uint>(options, new XDRPCArgumentInfo[] { info, info2, info3 });
        iprintln("gave weapon: " + (guns.ToString()));
        giveAmmo(clientIndex, guns);
        //switchToWeapon(clientIndex, 46);

    }
```

And I just want it to run on button click:

```
    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // Call void here

    }
```

Comment: Is `giveWeapon` in the same class as `button14_Click`?

Comment: why was it difficult for you to call it?

Comment: I've been coding for like 6 hours straight, just went a bit brain-blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void` is a keyword indicating that your **function** `giveWeapon` does not return a value. So your correct question would be: *"How can I call a function?"*

The answer:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int clientIndex = 5; // use correct value
    string weaponName = "Bazooka"; // use correct value
    giveWeapon(clientIndex, weaponName);
}
```

if `giveWeapon` is defined in a different class, you'd need to create an instance and call the method on that instance, i.e.:

```
ContainingClass instance = new ContainingClass();
instance.giveWeapon(clientIndex, weaponName);
```

---

As a side note, your code readability would benefit a lot from using [*implicitly typed local variables*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

```
public void giveWeapon(int clientIndex, string weaponName)
{
    uint guns = getWeaponId(weaponName);

    var options = new XDRPCExecutionOptions(XDRPCMode.Title, 0x822728F8);  //Updated
    var info = new XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint>(getPlayerState(clientIndex));
    var info2 = new XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint>(guns); // guns is already uint, why cast?
    var info3 = new XDRPCArgumentInfo<uint>(0); // same goes for 0
    uint errorCode = xbCon.ExecuteRPC<uint>(options, new XDRPCArgumentInfo[] { info, info2, info3 });
    iprintln("gave weapon: " + guns); // ToString is redundant
    giveAmmo(clientIndex, guns);
    //switchToWeapon(clientIndex, 46);
}
```

Comment: I coded it like this in order to show the errors, if you give me an example of what you mean I would be willing to give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Simply go:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    giveWeapon(clientIndex, weaponName);
}
```

As long as `giveWeapon` is in the same class as `button14` then it will work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

then call it

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   giveWeapon(10, "Armoured Tank");
}
```